# wrapper to template class inherited by another class

Tags: c++, wrapper

```
template <class CollectionItem>
class Collection
{
    void A();
    // Many other utility functions
}

class ICollection
{
   virtual void B() = 0;
}


class Base : public Collection<BaseItem>, public IBase
{
    virtual void B();
}
```

Is there any way of offering `Collection` functions via `ICollection` interface without wrapping all the functions in `Base` class? `ICollection : public Collection<CollectionItem>` is not an option.

Bounty Update:
OK, so the original idea was to have Interface to all Collection classes. Before we continue, every `CollectionItem` also has Interface, let's call it `ICollectionItem` and `ICollection` only knows about `ICollectionItem`.

So what I did was create another template class as Interface to Collection template class - `ICollection` (pure virtual) accepting `ICollectionItem(s)`. Collection class inherits this interface.

Every `Collection` class (inheriting `Collection<CollectionItem>` class) would also inherit it's Interface `Collection` class. That Interface then virtual inherits `ICollection<ICollectionItem>`. I'll just post the code :)

Here is the code:

```
template <class ICollectionItem>
class ICollection
{
public:
    virtual const ICollectionItem* At(const int idx) = 0;
};

template <class CollectionItem, class ICollectionItem>
class Collection
    : public ICollection,
      public virtual ICollection<ICollectionItem>    // Weak point
{
private:
    List<CollectionItem*> fContainer;

public:
    Collection(void) {}
    virtual ~Collection() {}

    virtual const ICollectionItem* At(const int idx);  // Casting GetAt result
    virtual const TCollectionItem& GetAt(const int idx) const 

    virtual ListIterator<TCollectionItem> >* GetIterator(void) const;
    virtual ListIterator<ICollectionItem> >* Iterator(void) const;  // Weak point
}
```

Example usage:

```
class IBaseItem
{
public:
    virtual int Number() = 0;
{

class BaseItem
    : public IBaseItem
{
public:
    virtual int Number();
    void SetNumber(int value);
}

class IBase
    : public virtual ICollection<IBaseItem>
{
public:
    virtual IBaseItem* ItemByName(String name) = 0;
    virtual ~IBase() {}
}

class Base
    : public Collection<BaseItem, IBaseItem>,
      public IBase
{
public:
    BaseItem* GetItemByName(String name);
    virtual IBaseItem* ItemByName(String name);
}
```

Weak points:

First is at using virtual inheritance ... lots written about it, not much to talk about, or is it?

Unable to access `Iterator` using `ICollection` interface. See `ListIterator` function, only first one can be implemented, the second one would require some kind of new List of `IBaseItem`. I decided to live with that and just use for loop.

Even tho I somehow managed to get what I wanted (With wrapping and casting), I would still like to hear an second opinion. I don't like using virtual inheritance, specially in such delicate situations - using Collections for application Base creation.

Comment: So you have an IBase pointer to an instance of Base?  And you want to call the Collection< T > functions from the IBase pointer without casting it to Base first?

Comment: Yes, I want to call `Collection <T>` functions using `IBase` pointer.

Comment: How about `Collection<BaseItem> : public IBase`?

Comment: Hmm .. might be possible, but would mean of having access to `Base` via two interfaces, `IBase` and another interfaces implemented by `Collection`. There are many other interfaces like `IBase` offering specific access.

Comment: I like @RalphTandetzky's idea.  Sounds like a `Collection` is something that provides the `IBase` interface, right?  `Collection<BaseItem> : public virtual IBase` may also be appropriate, especially if `IBase` has no data members.

Comment: The problem with this is, that `IBase` might need/offer 3 functions, another `Collection<BaseItem>` might need/offer another 3 functions. Template will have to implement all of them, which is not OK.

Comment: You may invert the logic and create template functions with some "requirements" on template Type as in <algorithm>.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see any other solution than calling some `Collection` method in `Base` implementation of `IBase` virtual methods.

```
class Base : public Collection<BaseItem>, public IBase
{
    virtual void B()
    {
        A();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you missed understood me, I have access to `B()`, but I don't have access to `A()` and I would like to avoid writing wrapper for it.

Comment: @krizajB: Maybe I am still not understanding well but when you are in `Base`, you have access to both.

Comment: Not when I want to access `Base` via `IBase` interface.

Comment: I still do not understand, `IBase` is just an interface so it does not "access" to anything, it even do not anything by itself. It is in `Base` implementation that you do the job.

Comment: `IBase` is interface that does not know anything about the `template class`, there for It does't provide any kind of access to template functions. When I say access `Base` via `IBase` I mean `IBase` provides access to `Base` which implements `IBase` functions. `IBase` is pure virtual interface.

Comment: So I think I can not help you more :). I am still interested to find a solution to this but I fear that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You say, and I quote:

> I want to call Collection  functions using IBase pointer

I really don't see what is to be done here besides `dynamic_cast`. It does exactly what you want it to do.

```
void fun(IBase * base) {
  auto * coll = dynamic_cast<Collection<BaseItem>*>(base);
  if (coll) {
    coll->A();
  }
}
```

Your `Collection` class **must** have a virtual destructor.

You can, of course, offer a templated version, if you'd need different baseitems in different, scenarios for some reasons. This has bad code smell and I think your architecture is bad at this point, but oh well.

```
template <typename T> void fun(IBase * base) {
   auto * coll = dynamic_cast<Collection<T>*>(base);
   if (coll) {
     coll->A();
   }
 }

void test(IBase * p) {
   fun<BaseItem5>(p);
}
```

If you have *some other specific scenario in mind*, **please** edit your question to say what you mean.

Comment: I will update the current scenario and let me know if there is anything to be optimized. It has it's weak points and it uses virtual inheritance. It does use casting and wrapping, but the main problem is that I can not implement functions like Iteration (which was worked around with for looping).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...So you wanna to reuse the **Collection** class's utility functions, and you want to design a class which will implement an interface defined by **IBase**.  As you mentioned above,"wrapping all the functions in Base class" is a way to  offer Collection functions.

(1) Via inheritance,derived class has a good knowledge of **Collection**

```
    class Derived：public Collection<DerivedType>,public IBase{};
```

or

```
    template <typename T> 
    class Derived：public Collection<T>,public IBase{};
```

(2) Via inheritance,derived class knows little about  **Collection**,but through **IBase**

```
class IBase : public Collection<BaseItem>{};
class Derived：public IBase{};
```

By (1),If you want to call Collection  functions using **IBase** pointer,you have to wrap the functions.
By (2), any **Derived** instance is " a kind of " IBase which is "a kind of " Collection.  So you can use **IBase** pointer to  call Collection  functions.

---

So,the key point is that the objects pointed by the **IBase** pointer should have the method you want to call.**Wrap** it or **inherit** it.  I can not see any other solution than these two ways.

Comment: What is designed class? Btw I can't wrap everything since it's a bit more complicated. Will update the current scenario tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments in another answer, it seems you want a collection of interfaces, and an implementation of this interface. The simplest I can advise you is the following:

```
template<typename T>
class ICollection
{
public:
    virtual iterator<T>* begin() const = 0;
};

template<typename T, typename TBase>
class Collection : public ICollection<TBase>
{
public:
    iterator_impl<T>* begin() const { return whatever; }
};
```

Example:

```
class IItem {};
class Item : public IItem {};

class Base : public Collection<Item, IItem> {};
```

old answer:

> > Is there any way of offering `Collection` functions via `IBase` interface without wrapping all the functions in `Base` class ?
>
> If I understood your problem, you want to use it like this:
>
> void myfunc()
>      {
>          // ...
>          IBase* obj = ...;
>          obj->A();
>          obj->B();
>      }
>
> I think here is a misunderstanding here: if you want `A()` to be callable from an `IBase`, then you have to add it to `Ibase` declaration.
>
> If you want to use the `Collection` functions on an object, then you should cast this object to a `Collection`, via `dynamic_cast` for example.
>
> Furthermore, if you have such a funcion:
>
> void fun(IBase* base) { /* ... */ }
>
> you **cannot** cast to a `Collection*`, since there are no relationship between these two classes, unless you have another way to be sure `base` is a `Collection`:
>
> void fun(IBase* base)
>      {
>          if(base && base->isABaseItemCollection())
>          {
>              // Valid, since the real type was checked before
>              Collection* collection = (Collection*)base;
>              // ...
>          }
>      }
>
> *On a side note: you can generate bases almost automatically:*
>
> template
>      class Base : public Collection, public U {};
>
> typedef Base BaseCollection;

Comment: I'm developing in Qt, there is an easy way creating Iterator from QList. But how can I return iterator of IItems if I only have  QList of Items?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear, to point out the problem. With my current solution I can only offer Iterator for Items, not IItems. I wish to have it both. And possibly without using virtual inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the idea is refined based on your example:
Here is an idea:

```
//generic interface can be kept as it is
template <class ICollectionItem>
class ICollection
{
public:
    virtual const ICollectionItem*          At(const int idx) = 0;
};
class Empty
{
};

template <class CollectionItem , class BaseClass = Empty>
class GenericCollection
    : public BaseClass
{
public:
    const CollectionItem*               At(const int idx);  
    // At and ItemByName are standard functions for a collection
    CollectionItem*                     ItemByName(String name);
    //note that here nothing has to be declared as virtual
};

//example usage:

class IBase
    : public virtual ICollection<IBaseItem>
{
public:
    virtual IBaseItem* ItemByName(String name) = 0;
    virtual ~IBase() {}
};

class Base
    : public GenericCollection<BaseItem, IBase >
{
public:
    //nothing to be implemented here, all functions are implemented in GenericCollection and defined as virtual in IBase
    //The definition of the functions has to be the same:
};
```

In collection you can implement whatever and in the interface you can define what ever you want to be virtual from your collection. The only thing is that you need to have some standard in naming convention for functions.

Hope this helps,
Raxvan.

Comment: Updated it, the example is a bit confusing , too much inheritance :), Your implementation could work also i think if all the functions have the same name , there is no need to have two names for a function that is supposed to do the same thing regardless if it is in an interface or a simple class

Comment: In my scenario it doesn't work, that's for sure :) Will analyze your code .. and yes, I agree it's a bit confusing .. that's why I'm here. 
Erm .. Can you please add some inline implementation of getters, thanks!

Comment: After a closer look to your code, i think what you are trying to do is to have a collection of BaseItem that can be work as an interface collection of but with IBaseItem, also all the functions to be in place, am i right ?

Comment: Argh, can you ask differently? :D Let me give you s quick example:
I want to have `ILayers` ("containing" `ILayer` items) implemented by `Layers` (containing `Layer` items). `ILayers` always return `ILayer` and `Layers` always return `Layer` (can also return `ILayer` .. but not really needed).

Comment: ok , now i understand your problem, let me think for a viable solution  :)

Comment: Wait .. How can I reform the question to accomplish better understanding? And just to be sure .. ILayers is interface class to Layers class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38894/discussion-between-raxvan-and-krizajb)

Answer (score 0):

According to comment/chat:

You have something like:

```
class IAnimal { /*...*/ };
class Cat : public IAnimal { /*...*/ };
class Dog : public IAnimal { /*...*/ };

class Cats
{
    std::vector<Cat*> cats;
public:
    Cat* at(size_t index) { return cats[index]; }
    /*...*/ 
};

class Dogs
{
    std::vector<Dog*> dogs;
public:
    Dog* at(size_t index) { return dogs[index]; }
    /*...*/
};
```

And you want to factorize some code using something like

```
class IAnimals
{
public:
    std::vector<IAnimals*> animals; // or getter/setter which works with IAnimals.
    /* some common factorized code */
};

// And so
class Cats : public IAnimals { /**/ };
class Dogs : public IAnimals { /**/ };
```

I propose, instead of creating `class IAnimals`, to use template functions as:

```
template <typename TAnimals>
void foo(TAnimals& animals)
{
    Ianimals* animal = animals.at(42);

    // ...
    animal->eat(food);
    // ...
}
```

You have to give compatible "interface" (names) to the type used in template.

Comment: I need to have separated interface for each Item, e.g. `class Cat : public ICat`, `class Dog : public IDog`

Comment: with `class ICat : public IAnimal`, I don't see any problem (except the name as here _Cat_ is too generic, as it should be several type of 'cat'). If this inheritance is not possible, you may use `auto* animals = animals.at(42)` in my foo example (with C++11). if c++11 is not an option, you may use some `typedef ICat AnimalType` inside classes and then use something like `typedef typename TAnimals::AnimalType AnimalType` to have "correct type"...

Comment: That inheritance is possible, but not usable in my case :) Every Item has it's own properties, there may or may not be any common properties  between difference Items. Never heard about auto*. But it seems that I just can't explain my problem good enough, even tho current code is included.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could have an operator() in IBase that would be delegated to Base?

```
class CollectionBase {};
template <class Item> class Collection: public CollectionBase {};

class IBase
{
public:
     virtual CollectionBase* operator()() = 0;
};

class Base : public Collection<BaseItem>, public IBase
{
public:
   virtual Collection<BaseItem>* operator()() { return this; }
};
```

Comment: you should not necessarily use operator overload for this, might be just a virtual function. Otherwise I totally agree.

Comment: Hmm .. still getting same error, i.e. class `IBase` `has no member named 'A'`

Comment: @Slava Indeed the op() is not a necessity, but I suggested it as it offers the interface of the collection somewhat "transparently"

Comment: @piwi What exactly do you expect `operator ()` to do here?

Comment: @SebastianRedl My bad it would require to offer the interface of Collection in CollectionBase

Comment: Got it to working calling `operator()()` ... would rename the function to `Collection()` or something .. but the problem is I can't declare functions in `CollectionBase` returning `Item` for example :(